# Use a calculator to compute the error $|e^x-T_2(x)|$ at $x=1.1$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I don't believe i have learned to solve for the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have computed $T_2$ at $x=0.8$
$$T_2=e^.8+e^.8(x-.8)+e^.8/2(x-.8)^2 $$

Comment: Plug $x = 1.1$ in the expression $|e^x - T_2(x)|$

Comment: Have you seen some theorem about the [remainder of the Taylor approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder)?

Comment: I do not understand. Since you say "use a calculator," why don't you just use a calculator, as @AlexZorn suggests? Or did you mean "*Do not* use a calculator"?